# XInputDotNet not working when building for UWP in Unity

Tags: unity

I am working on a game where a controller has to vibrate. I have found the XInputDotNet plugin which worked very well in the editor and a normal windows build, but if I build for UWP (both Xaml and D3D) the controller doesn't vibrate.

When building in unity for UWP it also gave me an error saying this:

```
Plugin 'XInputInterface.dll' is used from several locations:
Assets/Plugins/x86/XInputInterface.dll would be copied to
<PluginPath>/XInputInterface.dll
Assets/Plugins/XInputInterface.dll would be copied to
<PluginPath>/XInputInterface.dll
Plugin 'XInputDotNetPure.dll' is used from several locations:
 Assets/Plugins/x86/XInputDotNetPure.dll would be copied to
<PluginPath>/XInputDotNetPure.dll
 Assets/Plugins/x86_64/XInputDotNetPure.dll would be copied to
<PluginPath>/XInputDotNetPure.dll
Please fix plugin settings and try again.

UnityEditor.Modules.DefaultPluginImporterExtension:CheckFileCollisions(String)
UnityEditorInternal.PluginsHelper:CheckFileCollisions(BuildTarget) (at
C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Plugins/PluginsHelper.cs:25)
UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()
```

The only way I found to remedy this is by deleting one of the plugin folders.

I tried manually copying the ddl's to the build folder, but this didn't help. I tried using the 32 bit dll's and the 64 bit dll's, I tried building for x86 and x64 and I tried all three modes in visual studio(Debug,Master,Release).

I found some links to the Windows.Gaming.Input namespace, but I dont't know if it is possible to add this namespace to unity and if so how.

Does anybody have an idea how to fix my problem?

Answer (score 1):

Libraries for UWP must be compiled separately, they must be assigned to UWP only and configured correctly.

So I have ported XInputDotNet library for UWP apps.

You can download prebuilded binaries from [Unity Forum by this link](https://forum.unity.com/threads/xinputdotnet-and-uwp-for-xbox.584356/#post-4494568).
Also there is an instruction how to use it.

Using ported library you can continue using same code for different platforms.